# SVN commit error, "file" should be add, but is absent

Tags: linux, svn, commit

I have a problem with SVN.

I try to commit my project with : `svn commit -m "test test"`

And i have this error message (in french sorry) :

```
svn: Ãchec de la propagation (commit), dÃ©tails :
svn: '/var/www/racine/comos/com-include/Smarty/libs/templates_c/30c727fea15771e5c1efb79369eca746c90f3b3a.string.php' doit Ãªtre ajoutÃ©, mais est absent
```

He says the file `/var/www/racine/comos/com-include/Smarty/libs/templates_c/30c727fea15771e5c1efb79369eca746c90f3b3a.string.php` should be add, but is absent.

I don't understand. This file not exist in my project and not exist in my repository...

Do you have any ideas ? Thanks !

Comment: Just in case, have you tried doing an `svn cleanup` first on your directory?

Comment: Hum, sorry, i have find something :  svn revert --recursive /var/www/racine/comos/com-include/Smarty/libs/templates_c.. and it's ok !